# Securing WCF service using basicHttpBinding which supports streaming

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

My question is in regards to the best (aka "least painful") way to secure access to a WCF service that is only exposed to our company's internal users. The goal is to ensure that the service is only accessed via a single Windows forms application that each of our users has installed. When the service is called, I want the service to be able to validate that it was called from the permitted application.

The service to be secured uses basicHttpBinding, which supports streaming, so I believe I am limited to Transport level security.

Below are simplified versions of the `<bindings>` and `<services>` sections from my service's config file.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Service1Binding" transferMode="Streamed"/>    
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
    <service name="WCFServiceSecurity.Service1" 
        behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceSecurity.Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint address=""
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="WCFServiceSecurity.IService1"
            bindingConfiguration="Service1Binding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

Can anyone offer some details as to what actions I would need to take in order to implement security on this service?

*Note: I'm new to WCF and am not familiar with security at all, so let me know if I haven't provided enough detail.*

---

#### UPDATE:

As [suggested by marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845423/securing-wcf-service-using-basichttpbinding-which-supports-streaming/845640#845640), I'd like to secure the WCF service using some sort of username/password mechanism. This gives a little more direction towards an answer, but I'm still somewhat blurry on *how* to actually do this.

Because my service requires streaming to be enabled, I have to use basicHttpBinding and Transport level security (right?); further to that, the method contained in my service can only accept a Stream object.

Taking those constraints into consideration along with my preference to use username/password validation...

- How should I modify my service's config file to force username/password credentials to be supplied?
- How will my service validate the supplied credentials?
- How will my client application pass credentials the service when making a call?
- Will this require using SSL and, if so, will all client machines require a certificate as well?

---

#### UPDATE:

After explaining the trouble I've been having with securing this service to my boss, I was given the go-ahead to try the Windows Authentication route. Sadly, I've had no luck in implementing this type of authentication with my Streamed service (argh). After making the appropriate changes (as outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949012.aspx) - the only exception being that my `transferMode="Streamed"`) and accessing my service, I was presented with the following error:

> HTTP request streaming cannot be used in conjunction with HTTP authentication. Either disable request streaming or specify anonymous HTTP authentication.

I then stumbled upon the following quote [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f76011d7-29ba-4d27-9dc4-62ae72ca7721) which offers some clarification:

> **You can't do transport auth. with streaming.** If you have to use HTTP request streaming, you'll have to run without security.
>
> The way security works is:
>
> WCF Client makes an http request to the Server.
>
> The Server responds with something saying, "You aren't authorized, send me a basic/digest/etc credential."
>
> The Client gets that response and resends its message with the credentials tacked on.
>
> Now the Server gets the message, verifies the credentials, and continues.
>   Request Streaming isn't designed to work with that security pattern. If it did, it would be really slow, since the Client would send the entire stream, get the message from the Server that it wasn't authorized, then it would have to resend the entire stream with credentials.

So now I'm looking for opinions, **how would you secure your streaming-enabled WCF service?** As mentioned previously, some sort of username/password mechanism would be preferred. Feel free to think outside the box on this one...

Any help is **greatly** appreciated!

Comment: If its possible, change your binding to a StreamedRequest or StreamedResponse and you will be able to enable Transport Authentication. Use only Streamed binding if its a must but I'm sure you can split the Upload and Download into different endpoints to enable this security.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I found a lot of issues surrounding security/streaming while working on this problem. The hack (er...um...workaround) I finally ended up going with was to create a new DataContract that inherits MemoryStream and decorated it with a BaseStream property (for holding the data I want streamed) along with appropriate properties used for simple authentication.

Here is the resulting DataContract:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType( typeof( MemoryStream ) )] 
public class StreamWithCredentials : MemoryStream
{
    [DataMember]
    public Stream BaseStream { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The above DataContract ends up being the input parameter of my service's method. The first action my service takes is to authenticate the supplied credentials against known valid values and to continue as appropriate.

Now I do **know** that this is **not** the most secure option but my directive was to avoid using SSL (*which I'm not even sure is possible anyway - as stated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f76011d7-29ba-4d27-9dc4-62ae72ca7721)*) for this internal process.

That being said, this was the best solution to the above stated problem I could come up with, hope this helps anyone else stricken with this issue.

Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of things you could do:

- add a certificate to each and every machine that's allowed to use your service, and check for that certificate. That only allows you to exclude "unauthorized" machines - you cannot limit it to a specific application
- same as above, but include the certificate embedded in your winforms app and send it from there (do not store it in the machine's certificate store)
- require a username / password that only that particular app of yours knows about and can transmit to your service; e.g. someone else would not be able to present the appropriate credentials

EDIT 2: OK, so the username/password approach seems to get out of hand.... what if you just have basic transport security (SSL) for basic protection, and then use the `MessageContract` to define header and body of your SOAP message, include a specific value in the header, and then just check for that presence of the element in the header in your service?

Something like that:

```
[DataContract]
class YourRequestData
{
 ...
}

[MessageContract]
public class YourRequest
{
  [MessageBodyMember]
  public YourRequestData bodyData { get; set; }

  [MessageHeader]
  public string AppThumbprint { get; set; }
}
```

And then on your server in your code just check for the presence and the validity of that `AppThumbprint` code:

```
public Stream RequestStream(YourRequest request)
{
  if(AppThumbprintIsValid(request.AppThumbprint))
  {
     .... begin your streaming
  }
}
```

That might end up being a lot easier than the username/password security scenario.

Marc

Comment: I'd like to avoid adding certificates to client machines since the users of the application change often. I'd like to implement the username/password method you mentioned but I'm not sure how I would transmit those values to the actual service. The method being exposed by the service has streaming enabled so I wouldn't be able to pass those values as parameters (due to the method signature restrictions in place for a streaming-enabled service); can you recommend a method for passing a un/pw combo to the service and authenticating from within the service?

Comment: After I modify my service's config as above and run the service I get the error "BasicHttp binding requires that BasicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType be equivalent to the BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate credential type for secure messages. Select Transport or TransportWithMessageCredential security for UserName credentials.". 

I thought a streaming-enabled endpoint required Transport level security?

Also, in the <endpoint> tag, I think the binding value be basicHttpBinding instead of basicHttpConfiguration.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Marc, but unfortunately I don't think this approach (EDIT 2) will work for my specific scenario. The service method being called must both accept and return a Stream. Your answer raises an interesting idea; I suppose I could inherit a Stream and decorate it with some un/pw properties; this Stream could be the input parameter of my service method (not overly secure, mind you). But given the apparent flexibility of WCF, I have to assume there is a better way... hmmmm.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `basicHttpBinding` (for interop) you can only pass your credential at the message level. You have to set your security configuration to `TransportWithMessageCredential`.

To do that you have to create a SSL channel, so you need a certificate at server side, and it's not necesary for a cliente to have one.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but:

if you are using forms authentication for your WCf service (on asp.net), just add a login method to your service, in it you create the required cookie (formsAuthentication.Authenticate()). which is automatically sent with the response, the client can then call the stream API without needing extra parameters (a requirement for it to be STREAM) and you can check the identity in the streaming api before you fire off the returning stream.

As for securing access to the whole WCF, I get the feeling that embedding a certificate in the .net app is one way to go. they would have to ildump your app to get at it.

you can tell asp.net/wcf not to provide the wsdl, or more accurately, to not automatically generate the wsdl. Without wsdl access it gets much harder for them to generate a proxy....

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Windows authentication with Streaming and SSL, but you must use `TransportWithMessageCredential`:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="FileService.FileServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

You need to set in code `proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName` and `proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password`.

Comment: I thought TransportWithMessageCredential didnt work for basicHttpBinding, and only work with wsHttpBinding?

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to be an application that lives on the intranet it might be easiest to just create a new group in your Active Directory and only give members of that group the ability to use the service.

You can add Authentication (using windows credentials) with something like this:

```
<basicHttpBinding> 
 <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"> 
  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" /> 
 </security> 
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Could then Authorise by decorating the Interface to your services methods:

```
<PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role:="MyAppsUsers")> _ 
Public Function MyMethod() As String Implements IService.MyMethod
```

Heres a good link to Security in WCF. It has lots of How To's at the end (the one titled 'How To - Use basicHttpBinding with Windows Authentication and TransportCreditals' might be of use to you). 
[Wcf Secruity](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurityGuide/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=15892)

[Disclaimer: I'm also new to WCF and haven’t done this exact case before so apologises if this is slightly off!]

Comment: Since we are trying to ensure that the WCF service is only accessed from a single application, I don't think using windows credentials will do since those users could potentially call the service from outside of the application (correct me if I'm wrong). Supplying a username/password to the service seems like the way to go (from my limited experience). Thanks for the link to the WCF security guide, I'll also be looking at that to see what I can apply to my scenario.